# DocuSign API - Sign a document via API silently without sending email or redirecting to DocuSign UI

Tags: docusignapi, sign, auto, silent

Is there a way to sign a document via API silently without redirecting a user to DocuSign Signing UI or sending email?

Use case:

1. User connect to our application
2. User selects which documents need to be signed
3. User clicks sign button in our application (assume these documents ready for uploading)
4. Our app connects to DocuSign via a API and asked to sign those documents on behalf of the user (user by email for example. sometimes users might have accounts which got created via out application)?

In this case, user never able to see the DocuSign UI and our application does it for user silently.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DocuSign Signing Appliance to programmatically sign a document (no user interaction). It is an on-premises piece of equipment designed for a high volume of digital signatures.

Instead of that, the usual UX flow, as Drew indicated, is to embed the DocuSign signing ceremony into your application. In this case, no email is sent to the signer. The flow looks like this:

1. Signer (on your application) presses the `Sign` button.
2. Your application redirects the signer to the DocuSign signing ceremony.
3. The signer signs the document. The branding / chrome of the signing ceremony can include your company's logo, colors, etc.
4. After the signer has signed, DocuSign will redirect the signer's browser back to your application (to a URL you specify) so the signer can then continue to use your application.

You can try an example of this flow via workflow example #1 in our code examples:

- C# -- https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core
- PHP – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant
- Java – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant
- Node.js – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant
- Python – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant
- Ruby – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-ruby-auth-code-grant
- Curl (direct API) – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-curl

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign doesn't allow full white-labeling of the service. The closest you can get is directing the recipient to DocuSign for the signing ceremony through an Embedded Signing workflow, and then they are redirected back to your application after the fact.